# Lion won't run app built with Mountain Lion

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I am trying to get a OS X app I built using Xcode 4.4 on Mountain Lion to work on Lion as well.

Setting the *OS X Deployment Target* to 10.7 doesn't help. The app  still won't run on Lion. (The app won't open, clicking on it does nothing.)

I tried setting the base SDK to 10.7, but I get a lot of errors, because I am using `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` literals, subscripting as well as default synthesis of `@property`s all over the place.

According to the [Objective-C Feature Availability Index](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ObjCAvailabilityIndex/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012243) these features should work on Lion.

What could the problem be?

Comment: Have you tried running it in a debugger to see where it's crashing?

Comment: The app won't even open. I click on it and it does nothing.

Comment: Apps can do nothing in lots of different ways; perhaps the debugger will show you what the error is; for example does Lion even try to run the app etc.

Comment: Fire up Console.app.  Make sure “All Messages” is selected.  Launch your app.  Does it trigger any new messages in Console?

Comment: If you use the new literals, you have to use the OS X v10.8 SDK.

Comment: I get `Job appears to have crashed: Illegal instruction: 4` in the Console

Comment: Also `cannot form weak reference to instance (0x101d375d0) of class NSWindow`. I do have a weak reference to an NSWindow I use as a sheet. It works fine on Mountain Lion. Maybe I should make it an `assign` property.

Comment: I hadn't thought of looking at Console.app, especially because I myself don't have access to a Lion machine since I updated to Mountain Lion. Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NSWindow` doesn't support weak references in Lion. From the "Transitioning to ARC Release Notes":

> ## Which classes don’t support weak references?
>
> You cannot currently create weak references to instances of the
>   following classes:
>
> `NSATSTypesetter`, `NSColorSpace`, `NSFont`, `NSMenuView`, `NSParagraphStyle`,
>   `NSSimpleHorizontalTypesetter`, and `NSTextView`.
>
> Note: **In addition, in OS X v10.7, you cannot create weak references to
>   instances of** `NSFontManager`, `NSFontPanel`, `NSImage`, `NSTableCellView`,
>   `NSViewController`, **`NSWindow`**, and `NSWindowController`. In addition, in OS
>   X v10.7 no classes in the AV Foundation framework support weak
>   references. **For declared properties, you should use assign instead of
>   weak; for variables you should use __unsafe_unretained instead of
>   __weak.**
>
> In addition, you cannot create weak references from instances of
>   `NSHashTable`, `NSMapTable`, or `NSPointerArray` under ARC.

So yes, you should use `assign` instead when compiling for Lion. ([reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-SW17))